# gulp autoprefixer gives invalid icon content of font-awesome

Tags: gulp, font-awesome, gulp-sass, autoprefixer

I've just setup the following Gulp task for SASS, using gulp-autoprefixer which causing a problem handling font-awesome icon "content".

**The way it works (without gulp-autoprefixer)**

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {

  gulp.src(['./src/vendor/style.scss',
        './src/app/style.scss'])
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(concat('style.css'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'));

});
```

**That works fine** and it outputs the result I expect.

An example of the user-icon (**without gulp-autoprefixer**):

```
.fa-user:before {
    content: "";
}
```

---

**The way it breaks (with gulp-autoprefixer)**

If I now add autoprefixer to this task - like:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {

  gulp.src(['./src/vendor/style.scss',
        './src/app/style.scss'])
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(concat('style.css'))
      .pipe(prefix({
        browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions', 'Firefox ESR', 'Opera 12.1'],
        cascade: false
      }))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'));

});
```

The **output breaks** now. This is what I get for fa-user **(with gulp-autoprefixer)**:

```
.fa-user:before {
    content: "ï€‡";
}
```

It seems like there is a problem with the charset (UTF-8 / UTF-16).

Is there any possibility to avoid that behaviour with gulp-autoprefixer?

Answer (score 1):

Well, even it was a strange behavior (because it worked well without the gulp-autoprefixer), the solution was easier than I thought.

I've missed to add the `UTF-8` charset meta-tag in the documents `<HEAD>`.

So this tag fixed it:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this issue, changing the order of the sass compiler and prefixer fixed it for me. Prefixer first, then sass compiler:

`.pipe(
   autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 3 versions'],
      cascade: false
   })
)
.pipe(
   sass({
      outputStyle: 'compressed',
      includePaths: []
   }).on('error', error)
)`